# Additional Submit button for triggering mail

Tags: apex, visualforce, account

Here is my Requirement :-

I have a visual force View page of Account . I want an additional submit (other than Save) button on it . The condition is when user click on submit if any of the fields are vacant or not filled then button should give an error "Please fill the  all the field first " .
After user fills all the fields save it and  click on submit button then an email should be sent or we can say a workflow should be activated.

Comment: Your requirement is difficult to understand based on the information you've provided. More importantly, you aren't providing a specific question that this community can help you address...where are you stuck/what have you tried so far?

Comment: i want additional button (name is not concern here) , and on this button workflow should be triggered , but there is one more condition mail should trigger only when none of account fields are empty.

Comment: So, you've told us what you want, but you still haven't told us why you're not sure how to build this -> what your real question is. Please try to update your question to explain us how you're trying to solve this problem and what is blocking you in doing so.

Comment: Are you in essence saying that you want to replace the "Save" button with a button labeled "Submit"? Validation rules and Workflow only fire when a record is saved.

Comment: Sorry for the ruckus around here. I am following the @brian path. will update the community accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the field validation done server side and the message displayed as a `<Apex:PageMessage>`, or do you want to do the field validation done with JavaScript?

You can create an `<apex:commandButton>` such as:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!validateFieldsAndEmail}" value="Submit" id="theOtherButton"/>
```

and a controller method such as:

```
public void validateFieldsAndEmail() {
  // check if any fields are null
  // if any null, return PageMessage with Severity:Error saying to fill all fields
  // if none are null, create email using Mail.SingleEmailMessage and send 
}
```

Comment: I want the field validation on client side .